# Lista de objetos da View para controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, mvc, ddd

Tenho duas entidade Cliente e Endereço onde o cliente possui vários endereços. No momento do preenchimento do formulário, o usuário pode adicionar dois endereço no mesmo formulário e no momento do Submit, gostaria de receber os dados do cliente e mais de um endereço preenchido no mesmo formulário. 
 Como posso receber na minha Controller o Cliente preenchido com mais de um endereço com apenas um Submit ?

No Meu projeto MVC estou seguindo a estrategia de arquitetura DDD onde minha camada Aplication contem minhas ViewsModel com as classes ClienteEnderecoViewModel, ClienteViewModel e EnderecoViewModel onde conversa com minha camada de Apresentação ClienteController.

Minha ClienteEnderecoViewModel possui as seguintes prop abaixo

```
 public Guid ClienteId { get; set; }
 public string Nome { get; set; }
 public string Email { get; set; }
 public string CPF { get; set; }
 public ICollection<EnderecoViewModel> ListEnderecoViewModels { get; set; }
```

Minha ClienteController

```
    public ActionResult Create( ClienteEnderecoViewModel clienteEnderecoViewModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            _clienteAppService.Adicionar(clienteEnderecoViewModel);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(clienteEnderecoViewModel);
    }
```

Minha Create.CSHTML

```
    <h4>Endereco </h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Logradouro, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ListEnderecoViewModels, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Logradouro, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Numero, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Numero, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Numero, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Complemento, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Complemento, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Complemento, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você disse que teria dois endereços. Você já poderia criar o model adicionando dois endereços vazios e entregar para a View. É necessário fazer um `for` para gerar os `EditorFor` para cada item da coleção. Se for necessário adicionar mais endereços dinamicamente tem que fazer com JS para criar novos itens de formulário.

```
 public class ClienteViewModel {
    public Guid ClienteId { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string CPF { get; set; }
    public ICollection<EnderecoViewModel> ListEnderecoViewModels { get; set; }
 }

 public ActionResult Index() {
      var model = new ClienteViewModel(){
            ListEnderecoViewModels = new List<EnderecoViewModel>{
                new EnderecoViewModel(),
                new EnderecoViewModel()
            }
      };
      return View(model);
 }
```

**View**

Fiz o exemplo de apenas um Editor. Depois deve fazer para os demais.

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Nome, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Nome, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Nome, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>

@for(int i = 0; i < Model.ListEnderecoViewModels.Count; i++) {
    <div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ListEnderecoViewModels[i].Logradouro, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ListEnderecoViewModels[i].Logradouro, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ListEnderecoViewModels[i].Logradouro, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
}
```

**Controller**

Dessa forma, você consegue recuperar os dados do cliente e do endereço em um objeto único.

```
public ActionResult Salvar(ClienteViewModel model){
   // as propriedades do cliente estarão preenchidas bem como os endereços
    foreach(var endereco in model.ListEnderecoViewModels){
      _clienteAppService.Adicionar(endereco);
   }
   .....
}
```

Comment: obrigado pela resposta. A solução foi atendida apos a implementação.

Comment: Não entendi direito. Minha resposta solucionou seu problema?

Comment: Sim @Murílo ! Obrigado.